# Dynamic Programming - "maximize" matrix chain multiplication

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm now practice dynamic programming by myself. For the classic problem "matrix-chain multiplication" is to find the minimize number of scalar multiplication. Which is,

```
M[i,j] = 0 if i=j
       = Min(i<=k<j){M[i,k-1]+M[k,j]+Pi-1*Pj*Pk}
and its time complexity is O(n^3)
```

But I'm just curious what if I want to find the "maximization"(instead of min) of scalar multiplication, does it exist a optimal structure and is it possible to solve it in polynomial time?

Answer (score 3):

The exact same reasoning as the minimization applies:

- If you multiply *a<sub>1</sub> ... a<sub>i</sub>*, the resulting matrix dimension does not rely on the internal parenthetization.
- It follows that that if the optimal - that is, most expensive - partition of *a<sub>1</sub> ... a<sub>i</sub> ... a<sub>n</sub>* is to multiply the matrices from *1* to *i* and from *i + 1* to *n*, then it is composed of the optimal solutions to *a<sub>1</sub> ... a<sub>i</sub>* and *a<sub>i + 1</sub> ... a<sub>n</sub>*

Since the optimal substructure remains, you can use the same algorithm as minimization (of course, changing the criteria for optimality from minimum to maximum).

Comment: @Pwan A few points: 1. *O(n^3)* *is* polynomial, 2. Matrix chain multiplication has [known more efficient algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication#More_efficient_algorithms).